# JSON: using jq with variable keys

Tags: json, key, jq

I have input JSON data in a bunch of files, with an IP address as one of the keys. I need to iterate over a the files, and I need to get "stuff" out of them. The IP address is different for each file, but I'd like to use a single jq command to get the data. I have tried a bunch of things, the closest I've come is this:

```
jq '.facts | keys | keys as $ip | .[0]' a_file
```

On my input in *a_file* of:

```
{
    "facts": {
       "1.1.1.1": {
            "stuff":"value"
        }
    }
}
```

it returns the IP address, i.e. `1.1.1.1`, but then how do I to go back do something like this (which is obviously wrong, but I hope you get the idea):

```
jq '.facts.$ip[0].stuff' a_file
```

In my mind I'm trying to populate a variable, and then use the value of that variable to rewind the input and scan it again.

=== EDIT ===
Note that my input was actually more like this:

```
{
    "facts": {
       "1.1.1.1": {
            "stuff": {
                "thing1":"value1"
            }
        },
        "outer_thing": "outer_value"
    }
}
```

So I got an error:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:9): Cannot index string with string "stuff"
```

This fixed it- the question mark after `.stuff`:

```
.facts | keys_unsorted[] as $k | .[$k].stuff?
```

Comment: FYI: there's also an alternative solution to your ask - `jtc`. There, your json query would look like this: `jtc -w'<^(?:\d+\.){3}\d+$>L:[stuff]' *.json`. That would be an _input invariant_ solution - i.e., does not matter how your source JSON looks like (you may try adding as many outer encapsulations as you like), it'll always find the label by the _regex_ (simplified match of the ip address) and will return your `stuff`. PS. I'm the developer of the `jtc`.

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it right, but need the object value iterator construct, `.[]` to get the value corresponding to the key

```
.facts | keys_unsorted[] as $k | .[$k].stuff
```

This assumes that, inside `facts` you have one object containing the IP address as the key and you want to extract `.stuff` from it.

Optionally, to guard against objects that don't contain `stuff` inside, you could add `?` as `.[$k].stuff?`. And also you could optionally validate keys against a valid IP regex condition and filter values only for those keys.

Comment: My gosh, that was fast! Thanks! `.[]` to me looks like an array thingy. Too much bash/perl/C in my brain!

Comment: @MikeS: If you know about the functional programming term `map`, you can define that in jq like so: `def map(f): [ .[] | f ];` -- meaning, first you split each element of the implicit input list, then you apply the filter `f` to each of them, and then you gather them in a `[ ... ]` list; so here, `.[]` is the splitting part of `map`. So it's kind of the opposite of `[ ... ]` which gathers things in a list.